# Is there a way to stop Kafka consumer at a specific offset?

Tags: apache-kafka

I can seek to a specific offset. Is there a way to stop the consumer at a specific offset? In other words, consume till my given offset. As far as I know, Kafka does not offer such a function. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Eg. partition has offsets 1-10. I only want to consume from 3-8. After consuming the 8th message, program should exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, kafka does not offer this function, but you could achieve this in your consumer code. You could try use `commitSync()` to  control this.

> public void commitSync(Map offsets)
>
> Commit the specified offsets for the specified list of topics and partitions.
>   This commits offsets to Kafka. The offsets committed using this API will be used on the first fetch after every rebalance and also on startup. As such, if you need to store offsets in anything other than Kafka, this API should not be used. The committed offset should be the next message your application will consume, i.e. lastProcessedMessageOffset + 1.
>
> This is a synchronous commits and will block until either the commit succeeds or an unrecoverable error is encountered (in which case it is thrown to the caller).

Something like this:

```
 while (goAhead) {
     ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
     for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
         if (record.offset() > OFFSET_BOUND) {
            consumer.commitSync(Collections.singletonMap(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()), new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset())));
            goAhead = false;
            break;           
         }
         process(record);
     }
 }
```

You should set the "enable.auto.commit" to false in code above. In your case the OFFSET_BOUND could be set to 8. Because the commited offset is just 9 in your example, So next time the consumer will fetch from this position.

Comment: It will misbehave. You stop to process the records once a partitions reached the bounds. However there can be other partition's - which havent reached the bound -record waiting to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that partition offsets are continuous (i.e. not log compacted) you could configure your consumer (using `max.poll.records` config) so it reads certain number of records in each poll. This would let you stop at the offset you want.

Answer (score 0):

As I know `max.poll.records` is a client feature. Kafka fetch protocol has only bytes limitations https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#The_Messages_Fetch
So you will read more messages under hood in general